# I can't figure out how this switch statement is working?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

```
func performMathAverage (mathFunc: String) -> ([Int]) -> Double {
    switch mathFunc { 
    case "mean": 
        return mean 

     case "median":       
         return median 

     default:         
         return mode 
     }
}
```

I got this example from a swift learning book and its speaking of the topic of returning function types and this is just a part of the whole program I didn't want to copy and paste it all. My confusion is that the book says:

> "Notice in performMathAverage , inside the switch cases, we return
>   either mean , median , or mode , and not mean() , median() , or mode()
>   . This is because we are not calling the methods, rather we are
>   returning a reference to it, much like function pointers in C. When
>   the function is actually called to get a value you add the parentheses
>   suffixed to the function name. Notice, too, that any of the average
>   functions could be called independently without the use of the
>   performMathAverage function. This is because mean , median , and mode
>   are called global functions ."

The main question is: "Why are we not calling the methods?" 
and what do they mean we are returning a reference to it??

What do they mean by reference? Im just confused on this part.

Comment: Notice in the function signature the `([Int]) -> Double`. `performMathAverage` is returning a function that takes in an array of `Int` and returns a `Double`. Simply, the cases are returning functions that were defined in the code somewhere

Comment: I see, but returning a function to where?? Thats what is confusing me. Whys aren't the functions just called from the Cases?? @somtingwong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stated your main question as:

"Why are we not calling the methods?" and what do they mean we are returning a reference to it??

This is a little tricky to grasp at first, but what it's saying is that we don't want the result of the function, we want the function itself.

Sometimes things like this are easier to understand w/ a type alias:

Starting w/ `[Int] -> Int`, what we're saying there is "a function that takes an array of `Int`s and returns a single `Int`"

Let's make a type alias for clarity:

```
typealias AverageFunction = [Int] -> Int
```

Now our function (from your example) looks like this:

```
func performMathAverage(mathFunc: String) -> AverageFunction {
```

Although, the naming conventions here are pretty confusing since we're not performing anything, instead let's call it like this:

```
func getAverageFunctionWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> AverageFunction {
```

Now it's very clear that this method is functioning like a factory that returns us an average function based on the identifier we provide.  Now let's look at the implementation:

```
func getAverageFunctionWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> AverageFunction {
    switch identifier {
    case "mean": 
        return mean 
    case "median":
        return median 
    default: 
        return mode 
    }
}
```

So now, we're running a switch on the identifier to find the corresponding function.  Again, we're not calling the function because we don't want the value, we want the function itself.  Let's look at how we would call this:

```
let averageFunction = getAverageFunctionWithIdentifier("mean")
```

Now, `averageFunction` is a **reference** to the mean function which means we can use it to get the mean on an array of integers:

```
let mean = averageFunction([1,2,3,4,5])
```

But what if we wanted to use a different type of average, say median?  We wouldn't have to change anything except for the identifier:

```
let averageFunction = getAverageFunctionWithIdentifier("median")
let median = averageFunction([1,2,3,4,5])
```

This example is pretty contrived, but the benefits of this is that by abstracting a function out to it's type (in this case `[Int] -> Int`, we can use any function that conforms to that type interchangeably.

This is functional programming!

Comment: I really appreciate the help, you took some time in explaining this, I'm still a little confused to where the function was returned but thank a lot!

Comment: No problem, if you look at the switch statement, within each case, the function follows the `return`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: not really, I know the return when used to return a variable to a declared variable in the main program, but when returning a function not really....because where does the function go when it is returned? and where is the execution part of this function if it is returned somewhere?

Comment: It's pretty weird to abstract, but I think you're close!  The function doesn't actually go anywhere, we just assign a pointer to it, the same way we would to some other type of object.  The execution of the function comes later when we actually call it, so in my answer, where I have `averageFunction([1,2,3,4,5])`, that's where the execution happens.  It sees that `averageFunction` is pointing to `median`, and calls the implementation of `median` with the provided arguments.  Does that help clarify things a bit?  I'll be out for about 1.5 hours, but could chat more after if you'd like.

Comment: so does return median, infers that it goes and finds the median function and executes it?

Comment: It finds it and assigns it to a pointer, but it doesn't actually execute the function until we call the variable pointing to the function with the given argument.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) aspects of swift. Here functions are treated like [first class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) meaning you can treat them like variables.

*Why are we not calling the methods?*

You are not calling the methods, because you have no argument to apply. The point of the function is to determine **which** function you would like to use. Of course the name of the function is terrible and does not accurately represent what the function does. It should be more like `func determineMathFuncToUse`, then you could use it like

```
var myFunc = determineMathFuncToUse("median")
// Now, you would be able to use myFunc just like you would use median
// e.g. myFunc(some_array) == median(some_array)
```

Comment: I see, but returning a function to where?? Thats what is confusing me. Whys aren't the functions just called from the Cases??

Comment: @Ali because there is no second argument passed to the method. Again, the name of the function as defined is misleading. If you had something like `func performMathFunc(name: String, args: Array)` then you could easily just apply the function and return it.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to understand. In Swift you can store references to functions (the closest you can achieve in Objective-C is the reference to block).

```
func performMathAverage (mathFunc: String) -> ([Int]) -> Double
```

This is the function whose return type is:

```
([Int]) -> Double
```

As you can see the return type of this function is a function which accepts an array of `Int` and returns `Double`.

And in code you see that it returns one of three functions: `mean`, `mode`, and `median`. Each of these functions accepts an array of `Int` and returns `Double`.

Due to this code below:

```
let meanFunc = performMathAverage("mean")
let mean = meanFunc(someIntArray)
```

is identical to:

```
let mean = mean(someIntArray)
```

I hope this helps.

The reason why functions are NOT executed in code is because this example illustrates how you can STORE reference to functions.

It might be difficult to understand why you would want to do it in this particular case, but, hey, printing "Hello world" also seems meaningless :)

You are referring to an example in a tutorial so it is not strange that they are oversimplifying things. However, believe me, that in a real world there are many cases in which storing references to functions is very-very useful!

One obvious example is when you want to store reference to some completion handler which you want to execute at the end of some lengthy operation. And which can be different depending on the context from which you initiated this operation.

Comment: Thanks much! this is awesome, Im still a little confused on where the functions is returned to, but thank you.

Comment: let meanFunc = performMathAverage("mean") - function is returned to the meanFunc. And now meanFunc() is identical to mean(). Think of it as assigning new name to the 'mean' function ;)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you are effectively returning the function itself, and not the result of calling that function. In this case, it lets you choose a function (using the switch statement) and evaluate it later. A helpful way to think about it is that functions are also a type of variable, and you can pass them around as well as evaluate them.

As a general stylistic thing, it's good practice to end each `case` with a `break`. It makes no difference here because `return` will also end the execution of the function, but without a break, all code **after** the correct `case` will be executed, not just the code **within** the correct `case`. Running into another `case` statement doesn't break out of the switch statement by itself.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it still a little confused but thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If there's anything you need clarification on I can try to make it easier to understand.

Comment: basically where the function is returned, say for example the mean function....where is it returned? and if it is returned then how will it execute??

Comment: This code gets executed where you call the `performMathAverage` function (most likely in your main function). You can then store the function it returns and execute it later. Does that make a little more sense?

Comment: so the functions in the switch statement are executed when called in main?

Comment: because the only thing being called is the performMathAverage function which executes the switch statement, seems like this is just looping(not program speaking, english speaking) and not getting to something.

Comment: If you call them. When you call `performMathAverage`, it will return a function (either `mean` `median` or `mode`). You can store that function and then call it later in your main function.

Comment: var mathFunc = performMathAverage("mean")  /*new line starts here */                                              mathFunc([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8,13]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it allows you to do. Does that make it a bit clearer?

Comment: that call is calling the performMathAverage func which chooses a case in the switch statement which returns a function.........confused on where the execution is happening lol sorry this is mind boggling to me right now.

Comment: You're saying the execution is happening in the call....but you're also saying the function being called is only referencing a function......my confusion here is where is the execution happening because clearly its not happening in the call from what you say due to.....agian the call is leading to "referencing" and NOT "executing"

Comment: The execution happens on that next line when you call `mathFunc(...)`. The switch is choosing which function `mathFunc()` actually is.

Comment: ahh, I see, finally get it right now! This is great! thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are we not calling the methods?

Presumably, the method will be called later. The purpose of the switch statement is to return a function that can be used later.

> What do they mean we are returning a reference to it? ... What do they mean by reference?

The "reference" language is a bit confusing - functions are reference types, but that isn't super important to what is going on. You can think of it as just returning a function.

The bottom line is that functions in swift can be used like any other type - they can be stored in variable or constants, they can be passed into a function as a parameter, and they can be returned from a function.

In this case, you have a function that is designed to return a function. If you want to obtain the mean, you pass the string "mean" and the function will return a new function that will obtain the mean when you call it.

Comment: Thank you so much, still a little confused on where the function is returned but I appreciate the help, thanks a lot!